# How to count number of lines in a file, between the values that repeat in a text file

Tags: python

I want to count the number of lines from a text file after `'A'` and before `'A'` repeats in the following example:

```
A1
   Apple
   Mangoes
   Oranges
A2
   Strawberries
   Grapefruit
A3
   Papaya 
   Sweet_lime
```

I want the result to be as

```
A1: 3, A2: 2, A3: 2
```

So far I have tried this:

```
f = open("temp.txt","r")
count = 0
A_vals = []
for lines in f:
    value = re.search("(A\d)",lines)
    header = value.group(1)
    if header in lines:
        count += 1
    A_vals.append(count)
```

I am not getting the expected result. Any help appreciated!

Comment: Do you have a more rigorous than "contains A" for the header lines?  The word "Apple" contains "A", but you don't seem to think of it as a header.

Comment: Sorry ! updated the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have `A` and then a number, use regular expressions to match the pattern.  You can use default dict as the counter.

```
import re
from collections import defaultdict

A_vals = defaultdict(int)
current_A = None

with open('temp.txt') as fp:
    for line in fp:
        m = re.match(r'A\d+', line)
        if m:
            current_A = m.group()
            continue
        if current_A:
            A_vals[current_A] += 1

print(dict(A_vals))
# prints:
{'A1': 3, 'A2': 2, 'A3': 2}
```

Comment: Hi, This works only thing that is happening is it is counting the new lines also. How do I ignore that ?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean.  Can you give an example of what the issue is, and what the expected result should be?

Answer (score 0):

If temp is formatted in a reliable fashion, this works.
With Temp.txt as:

```
A1
        Apples
        Mangoes
        Oranges
A2
        Strawberries
        Grapefruit
A3
        Papaya
        Sweet_Lime
END
```

then...

```
counter=0
returnString = ""
with open("temp.txt", "r") as file:
    currHeader=file.readline()[:-1]
    for i in file.readlines():
        if "\t" not in i:
            returnString+="{}: {}, ".format(currHeader, counter)
            counter=0
            currHeader = i[:-1]         
        else:
            counter+=1
print(returnString.rstrip(" ,"))
```

returns:

```
A1: 3, A2: 2, A3: 2
```

so as we inspect the lines individually, if there's no tab character (due to the indent) then the line should be considered the "header" for this section. We use [:-1] to strip the newline character from the end of the line. Then we count the lines until the next header. Counter is reset at the sight of a new header section. We used END as the last header, which won't be printed out since there are no values after it.

Comment: No, I want to segregate the content based on the values and not tab spaces ! That is something really impractical !

Comment: See output. The values are segregated properly. If you cannot rely on the formatting of your input file you need to sort that out first of all.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you can access the whole content of the file, you could split the content by header (keeping them), and then zip the results:

```
import re

pattern = re.compile('A\d+')

content = """A1
   Apple
   Mangoes
   Oranges
A2
   Strawberries
   Grapefruit
A3
   Papaya
   Sweet lime"""

chunks = re.split('(A\d+)', content)
non_empty_chunks = [chunk for chunk in chunks if chunk]

result = {key: len(text.splitlines()) - 1 for key, text in zip(non_empty_chunks[0::2], non_empty_chunks[1::2])}
print(result)
```

**Output**

```
{'A2': 2, 'A1': 3, 'A3': 2}
```

Note than in the case of no elements to count it returns `0`, for instance:

```
content = """A1
   Apple
   Mangoes
   Oranges
A2
A3
   Papaya
   Sweet lime"""
```

**Output**

```
{'A1': 3, 'A3': 2, 'A2': 0}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I tried.

### Code:

```
f = open("temp.txt","r")
Result=[]
S=0 # State 0.
Lines=0
for i in f.read():
    if S==0:
        if i=="\n":
            S=1
            Lines+=1
    elif S==1:
        if i=="A":
            Result.append(Lines-1)
            Lines=0
        S=0
Result.append(Lines)
f.close()
print(*("A"+str(i+1)+": "+str(Result[i])for i in range(len(Result))),sep=", ")
```

### Text:

```
A1
   Apple
   Mangoes
   Oranges
A2
   Strawberries
   Grapefruit
A3
   Papaya 
   Sweet_lime
```

### Result:

```
A1: 3, A2: 2, A3: 2
```